# C# continuously watching file that is being recreated

Tags: c#, file, filesystemwatcher

I am trying to continuosly watch a log file that is being deleted and rewritten every it gets updated.

My current approach was to use the FileSystemWatcher. This works great when modifying the file but if I delete the file and make a new one with the same name it stops tracking it.

My current approach:

```
namespace LogReader
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Watch();

            while (true)
            {

            }
        }

        public static void Watch()
        {
            var watch = new FileSystemWatcher();
            watch.Path = @"C:\TEMP\test";
            watch.Filter = "test.txt";
            watch.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess | NotifyFilters.LastWrite;
            watch.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
            watch.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        }

        private static void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.FullPath == @"C:\TEMP\test\test.txt")
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Stream stream = File.Open(@"C:\TEMP\test\test.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);
                StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(stream);
                var lines = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                Console.Out.WriteLine(lines);

                streamReader.Close();
                stream.Close();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You could watch for created and deleted too.

Answer (score 4):

This is because Create and Delete operations will not Trigger `OnChanged` event of FileSystemWatcher. So you need to register those events and assign the same event handler `OnChanged` It will be like the following:

```
 watch.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
 watch.Deleted += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
```

You can go through [This](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx) For more information regarding FileSystemWatcher.

Comment: Yeah, I also had to add the `NotifyFilters.CreationTime` filter. Thanks.

Comment: [It](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.notifyfilters(v=vs.110).aspx) is not necessary for Creation event

Comment: Creating the file didn't trigger LastAccess or LastWrite so in this case it was.

Comment: @RusinaRange: that is for onChange

Answer (score 1):

I was only watching for file changes not file creations. Changing the watch function to this fixed it.

```
    public static void Watch()
    {
        var watch = new FileSystemWatcher();
        watch.Path = @"C:\TEMP\test";
        watch.Filter = "test.txt";
        watch.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess | NotifyFilters.LastWrite | NotifyFilters.CreationTime; //more options
        watch.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
        watch.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
        watch.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    }
```